# Proper way to handle a fail to init

Tags: swift, ios8

I am looking for a proper way to handle a invalid argument during a initialization.

I am unsure how to do it using Swift as the init has't a return type. How can I tell whoever is trying to initialize this class that you are doing something wrong?

```
init (timeInterval: Int) {
    if timeInterval > 0
        self.timeInterval = timeInterval
    else
        //???? (return false?)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would say force it by making `timeInterval` unsigned? Or you would have to assert it..

Comment: Making it unsigned would kind of solve this particular case, but no many others. Assets sounds like a option. It kind of sucks tho...

Comment: You could use a class function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250363/how-should-i-handle-parameter-validation-swift/24250645#24250645.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a *failable initializer*. Such an initializer looks very similar to a regular designated initializer, but has a '?' character right after `init` and is allowed to return `nil`. A failable initializer creates an optional value.

```
struct Animal {
    let species: String
    init?(species: String) {
        if species.isEmpty { return nil }
        self.species = species
    }
}
```

See [Apple's documentation on failable initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_339) for more detail.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, but bailable initializers are a great way to conditionally create objects.

Answer (score 3):

In swift, you can't really abort a task half way through execution. There are no exceptions in swift and in general the philosophy is that aborting a task is dangerous and leads to bugs, so it just should't be done.

So, you verify a value like this:

```
assert(timeInterval > 0)
```

Which will terminate the program if an invalid value is provided.

You should also change `timeInterval` to be a `UInt` so that there will be a compiler error if anybody tries to give a `< 0` value or an integer value that could be < 0.

It's probably not the answer you're looking for. But the goal is to check for bad parameters as early as possible, and that means doing it *before* you create any objects with those parameters. Ideally the check should be done at compile time but that doesn't always work.

Comment: Nice! also you can provide a message for your assertion just like an error message

Comment: Assertion is fine if you want to terminate the app when it fails. However, there are many scenarios in which this would be inappropriate. If a user tries to create an instance with invalid arguments, I may want to inform that user, not crash the app.

Comment: @codingTheHole in swift you are not ever meant to fail to init an object. Anything that could cause a failure must be checked for before calling init, and assert is used to crash the app if somebody failed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best solution, took it from:[How should I handle parameter validation Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250363/how-should-i-handle-parameter-validation-swift/24250645#24250645)

```
class NumberLessThanTen {
    var mySmallNumber: Int?
    class func instanceOrNil(number: Int) -> NumberLessThanTen? {
        if number < 10 {
            return NumberLessThanTen(number: number)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    @required init() {
    }
    init(number: Int) {
        self.mySmallNumber = number
    }
}

let iv = NumberLessThanTen.instanceOrNil(17) // nil
let v = NumberLessThanTen.instanceOrNil(5) // valid instance
let n = v!.mySmallNumber // Some 5
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Swift book by Apple, at the very bottom of this section:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399

They say:

> When to Use Assertions
>
> Use an assertion whenever a condition has the potential to be false,
>   but must definitely be true in order for your code to continue
>   execution. Suitable scenarios for an assertion check include:
>
> An integer subscript index is passed to a custom subscript
>   implementation, but the subscript index value could be too low or too
>   high. A value is passed to a function, but an invalid value means that
>   the function cannot fulfill its task. An optional value is currently
>   nil, but a non-nil value is essential for subsequent code to execute
>   successfully.

This sounds **exactly** like your situation!

Thus your code should look like:

```
init (timeInterval: Int) {
    assert (timeInterval > 0, "Time Interval Must be a positive integer")

    // Continue your execution normally
}
```