# checking parameters of init method

Tags: class, swift, initialization

I'm facing a kinda stupid problem trying to code my first swift classes.
I'm writing an init method for my class, and I want to (raise an exception)/(do something in some way) to report an error when the parameters that have been passed to the initializer are wrong.
My class is simple as that:

```
class Phrase: NSObject {
    let name : String
    let voices : Array<Voice>
    init(name: String, voices: Array<Voice>){
        if (name == "" || voices.count == 0){
          //do something!
        }
        self.name = name
        self.voices = voices
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to handle a fail to init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295740/proper-way-to-handle-a-fail-to-init)

Comment: possible duplicate af [How should I handle parameter validation Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250363/how-should-i-handle-parameter-validation-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my favorite option:

```
fatalError("This is an overreaction.")
```

You can also do:

```
NSException(name: "Invalid Arguments", reason: "Arguments are empty", userInfo: nil).raise()
```

More on this [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010569/error-handling-in-swift-language)

Comment: The first one is so BRUTAL ;)
The second one is an exception but I cannot manage it in Swift, and because this wants to be a full swift project it seems kinda useless!
I'll go for the first one! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `init` for this - use a class function that can return `nil` if the parameters are invalid:

```
class Phrase: NSObject {
    var name : String
    var voices : Array<Voice>

    init() {
        self.name = "something safe"
        self.voices = [Voice]()
    }

    class func phraseOrNil(name: String, voices: Array<Voice>) -> Phrase? {
        if (name == "" || voices.count == 0){
            let p = Phrase()
            p.name = name
            p.voices = voices
            return p
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

...then you can fail gracefully (or throw an exception if you really want to, as shown above) in the main code. See also [How should I handle parameter validation Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250363/how-should-i-handle-parameter-validation-swift), though that doesn't deal with your exception question.

Note also that I changed your `let` declarations to `var` as we need to change their values.

Comment: On top of that I would suggest using NSError, to provide additional info to the user of your code.